# Can I implement a counter for multiprocessing using pool callback?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I googled a bit for how to correctly building a counter to keep track of the progress of work done. So far it seems all answers involved the use of `lock` and `Value`.

I am wondering if I can achieve it using the callback. It seems that the callback is executed in the main process, not the child process that the workers live in. Can I assume further it is executed in the same thread, thus no racing condition at all?

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import os

Pool = multiprocessing.Pool

def sqr(a):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'local {}'.format(os.getpid())
    return a * a

pool = Pool(processes=4)


class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def incr(self, x):
        self.value += 1
        print 'count {}'.format(self.value)
        print 'callback {}'.format(os.getpid())


counter = Counter()

r = [pool.apply_async(sqr, (x,), callback=counter.incr) for x in range(10)]
pool.close()
pool.join()

local 27155local 27154local 27156


count 1
callback 27152
count 2
callback 27152
count 3
callback 27152
local 27153
count 4
callback 27152
local 27155
count 5
callback 27152
local 27156
local 27154
count 6
callback 27152
count 7
callback 27152
local 27153
count 8
callback 27152
local 27155
count 9
callback 27152
local 27156
count 10
callback 27152
main 27152
main count 10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Update

Ok, it seems this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770934/who-runs-the-callback-when-using-apply-async-method-of-a-multiprocessing-pool) explained a bit of the mechanism behind callback.

So actually it runs on a different thread in the main process.

However, can I still implement the counter in the same way, as there is only 1 thread that modifies the counter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who runs the callback when using apply\_async method of a multiprocessing pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770934/who-runs-the-callback-when-using-apply-async-method-of-a-multiprocessing-pool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the SO link in @ami-tavory's comment, it seems like the callbacks might all be called on the same thread.  Since this is not specified in the docs or api, though, I would not rely on it as it might change in the future or depending on implementation.

Python does not have an atomic increment (except some [itertools trick that relies on the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062830/618895)), so to be sure you're threadsafe you must use a lock or some other form of synchronization.  Why are you trying to avoid it?  It can be used as a contextmanager which makes the code is very minimal:

```
from threading import Lock

class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.lock = Lock()

    def incr(self, x):
        with self.lock:
            self.value += 1
```

An alternative would be to use [`imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered), looping on the results as they become available (in the main thread) and updating your progress/counter there.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could count in the loop using imap_unordered as bj0 mentioned:

```
results = []
for count, result in enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(sqr, range(10)), 1):
    results.append(result)
    print(count)
```

Personally, I find it more straight forward to deal with raw results returned by `imap_unordered()` than the Result object returned by `apply_async()`.